# in my sql statement I call sum twice for the same argument, is it duplicating the effort?

Tags: sql, sql-server

consider my sql query below; it is calling sum twice for the same argument. IS this duplicating the work done by the server. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT      Status_Detail_Code, count(*) as 
   [Number of times assigned], round(sum(Duration)/60,2) as [total duration Hr]

 FROM         dbo.V_TIMELINE

 WHERE     (CADATE > N'20080101')  

group by Status_Detail_Code order by sum(Duration) desc
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, `SQL Server` reuses the aggregates.

In fact, if you build the query plan, you will see the `SUM` in a result set of an aggregation operator (like `Stream Aggregate`) denoted as something like `Expr****`.

The value of this expression will later be used as an input to the other operators.

Here's the sample query:

```
SELECT  ROUND(SUM(id), -1)
FROM    master
GROUP BY
        name
ORDER BY
        SUM(id) DESC
```

and it's plan:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=round([Expr1003],(-1))))
       |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1003] DESC))
            |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([test].[dbo].[master].[name]) DEFINE:([Expr1003]=SUM([test].[dbo].[master].[id])))
                 |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[master].[ix_name_desc]), ORDERED BACKWARD)
```

As you can see, the aggregation is done once and stored in `Expr1003`.

`Expr1003` is then reused in both the `Sort` operator (which processes the `ORDER BY`) and `Compute Scalar` (which processes `ROUND`)